# Particle nature of radiation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, frequency

If quantum of radation concept is used to define particle nature of radiation, then why it has a frequency?(E=hv)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly does the \*frequency\* of a photon mean?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/303458/)

Comment: I saw that post it explained that photon has a frequency , but my question is that if particle theory is used to overcome drawbacks of wave theory , then why quanta has a frequency just like waves .

Comment: See the question [Frequency of a photon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/151068/) which directly address your question.

Comment: Thanks but they have explained it by using concepts that i have not studied yet.

Comment: @user58660 - well, if it were explained using concepts you knew already, then you would know it. It is great you asked the question - you will find that good answers to questions will lead to other good questions!

Comment: The photon behaves like a particle and a wave, both are correct to use depending on the problem.

Comment: I know but if we consider light to be of particle nature then it means that it transmits in the form of packeta of energy called quanta, but quanta itself has a frequency and acts like a wave then how particle nature is justified by quanta(which itself has a wavelenght and frequency)