# Why do we associate photoelectric effect with particle nature?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

It is said that wave theory couldn't explain this effect and yet we shamelessly associate a frequency with light ($E = h\nu$) and call photoelectric effect as a failure of wave theory. Associating a frequency and calling it particle nature seems contradictory to me. Where is this wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly does the \*frequency\* of a photon mean?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303458/what-exactly-does-the-frequency-of-a-photon-mean)

Comment: For massive particles see [How does the frequency of a particle manifest itself?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108471/how-does-the-frequency-of-a-particle-manifest-itself)

Comment: Your question is fundamentally flawed because it fails to understand the existence of wave-particle duality.

Answer (score -1):

We can measure the frequency of light, which does not interact with material except being reflectet or absorbed, so we know f. On the other hand we can measure the energy light transfers to electrons. If we increase the intensity of light this energy doe not get beyond hf, we just get more electrons.
Now to find out the energy of the photon we have to use f, since we found out, the larger f, the greater the energy of the electron.

Comment: This explanation is nowhere related to the question. Please go through the question again.

Comment: I can not understand your comment, I thought I answered your question, wave theory says, the energy should depend from amplitude.